# How to import / reference a gradle application in android application using command line (ant)

Tags: android, maven, ant, gradle

I am using the android command line tool (ant and adb) to manage my application.

As the project has no "gradle" specifications, I am wondering how I am to import the following gradle library (android google datepicker).

```
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker
```

The files found at the root of my application are

```
$ ls
AndroidManifest.xml  build.xml  local.properties      res
ant.properties       gen        proguard-project.txt  src
bin                  libs       project.properties
```

I use the following commands to build and install my application

```
$ ant debug
$ adb install -r <path to apk>
```

Comment: Google has been advising developers to stop using Ant and switch to Gradle and the Gradle for Android plugin for about 18 months.

Comment: Yep, I know. But I wondering if there is still a way. I am am, trying to migrate my application gradle.